# How can I execute ALTER DATABASE $current_database in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do this in a SQL script that I feed into `psql`:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET SEARCH_PATH TO myschema,public
```

but I need `dbname` to be dynamically set to the current database rather than hard coded.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ALTER DATABASE (select current_database()) SET SEARCH_PATH TO myschema,public;
```

Comment: Could you create a wrapper around this SQL script in Bash/Perl/Ruby/your favorite scripting language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot execute such a statement in plain SQL, where identifiers cannot be parametrized.
You could write a [plpgsql function to execute dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

With PostgreSQL **9.0** or later you can also use a [`DO` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html):

```
DO $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE '
ALTER DATABASE ' || current_database() || ' SET SEARCH_PATH TO myschema,public';
END; $$;
```